# Export current MS Access Form record to PDF

Tags: forms, ms-access, pdf

I have created a form that looks fairly good. I'm trying to refrain from creating a report so I am trying to have the form export the record that i am currently on, to PDF. The catch is that i only want that 1 record that im on to be exported to PDF.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to install a **Print to PDF** driver. [**Here's one I've used in the past.**](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp)

Then when you go to print, you select the PDF printer. The PDF printer is system wide on your computer, so you can **print to PDF** from any application.

Comment: Hey Tom. This works great. The only problem i have is that the form length is about 3 letter size pages long. So is there any way to get rid of the blank pages when printing to PDF? i Currently have the "Can Shrink" and "Can Grow" commands on all fields so majority of the time the report itself is 1-2 pages...

Comment: Myself, I would create a report instead of printing the form. You can take the form and do a 'save as report", then you can tweak the report better.